# Getting value from database on drop down menu selection change

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

I am calling a method to populate a drop down menu in asp.net web forms. The method calls a stored procedure that retrieves a list of names. It also retrieves a member ID from the DB. All of this works great, however, I'm needing the member ID field to change with each associated name in the drop down menu. For example, I select the name Barney Fife from the drop down and it returns Member ID '1'. The problem is when i select a different name from the drop down - the Member ID isn't changing. Here's my C# method for retrieving the data:

```
        public void GetMemberName()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spGetMemberNames", con))

                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    { 
                        sda.Fill(ds); // ds is declared in the scope.
                        cmbNames.DataSource = ds;
                        cmbNames.DataTextField = "FormattedName";
                        cmbNames.DataValueField = "FormattedName";                    

                        cmbNames.DataBind();                            
                    }
                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            lblMemberID.Text = (read["MemberID"].ToString()); // Places the member ID associated with the name in a label.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMemberNames]

AS
BEGIN
        SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName [FormattedName],MemberID
        FROM tblMembers
        ORDER BY LastName
END
```

Do I need to call a whole different method and stored procedure that connects to the DB and looks up the member ID based on the FormattedName (from my stored procedure) on DropDown SelectedIndexChange?

Here is my SelectedIndexChange event.

```
        protected void cmbNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMemberID.Text = "";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spGetMemberNames", con))

                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        cmbSelectTable.DataSource = ds;
                        cmbSelectTable.DataTextField = "FormattedName";
                        cmbSelectTable.DataValueField = "MemberID";
                        cmbSelectTable.DataBind();
                    }
                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            lblMemberID.Text = (read["MemberID"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblWarning.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you post a form, the VALUE of the drop down gets passed, not the text.  You currently have: `cmbNames.DataValueField = "FormattedName";` .   I believe you want to use the Member ID instead of the FormattedName as the value of the drop down options.

Comment: Actually, the MemberID value will be hidden from the user in a hidden label that gets passed to another form. However, this does give me the idea of creating a hidden drop down box that also contains the member ID's only. I was hoping for an easier solution though.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this.  The user does not see the value field only the text field.  No need to have an additional hidden label unless its for some other purpose (also still not needed).  Right now you have nothing available to change the ID when the selection in the names ddl is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so easy. Here's the solution:

```
protected void cmbNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = cmbNames.SelectedValue;
    lblMemberID.Text = value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set autopostback attribute of the dropdownlist to true.

Comment: I have done this but it still doesn't change the label.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbNames" runat="server" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbNames_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Share your dropdownlist markup with us. Additionally, the dropdownlist's SelectedValue property contains MemberID of the selected item. Change cmbNames.DataValueField="MemberID" . Change readonly to false if you want user to select her desire item.

Comment: I have added the dropdownlist change event in the original post.